# Where did my desktop preview icons go?

Tags: icon, desktop, ui

When I started up my MacBook today my preview icons where gone as can be seen by attached screenshot.

Any clue why they disappeared? And how to get them back?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the desktop, press Command+J or select Show View Options from the View menu to bring up the view options. From there, select "Show Icon Preview."

[image: Show Icon Preview]

Comment: Thanks! Strangely enough the problem had fixed itself already. My computer is a bit off this week. When I started uTorrent it said that it was started for the first time. So something strange is going on. I wish I knew what.